# access variable after define it inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to access a variable outside a function, but I'm getting undefined

```
 meliObject.get('users/me', function (err, res) {
           nickname = res.nickname;
  });

console.log(nickname);
```

How can I access nickname?

EDIT

I changed my code for:

```
var nickname;

        meliObject.get('users/me', function (err, res) {

            nickname = res.nickname;


        });

        console.log(nickname);
```

But I'm still getting undefined

Comment: This question is your initiation to callbacks. Welcome!

Comment: @NickA — No. That variable is a global. This is about time, not scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of that function is asynchronous, so you cannot do this. Javascript flow goes like this: run `meliObject.get`, return immediately, run console.log(nickname), and then wait for the callback to be called. To console.log properly, just do this:

```
meliObject.get('users/me', function (err, res) {
   nickname = res.nickname;
   console.log(nickname);
});
```

Now, to answer your question, to declare a variable outside a function, just use var/let/const:

```
var a = 2;
(function () {
    a = 3;
})();
console.log(a);
```

It will print as expected.

Comment: I changed my code in the question, but I'm getting undefined

Comment: That's because of the first problem I described; your error was not scope, but actually asynchronousness. You need to put the console.log inside the callback function, because the order in which JS runs things (see my first paragraph for more details)